# Express-session req.session not persisting

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

I'm currently using express session with connect-session-knex as the store and my issue is that the session does not persist between API calls. Any variables set to req.session are inaccessible during later requests, and the sessionID is different each time as well.

For example, in the code below, calling login will correctly set req.session.user (and I can see this reflected in the database and with console.log) but then when checkAuth is called after, req.session.user will be undefined because a new session has been started.

I've read the other answers on this topic and tried each of the suggested fixes (manually calling req.session.save, checking cors configurations, reordering middleware calls, setting "secure: false" in express-session configs, setting "credentials: include" on the client side) but none of them seem to work. Would greatly appreciate any suggestions!

**1. Configurations**

```js
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
  }))

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false, 
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: false, 
    maxAge: 14400000, 
    sameSite: true,
    secure: false
  }
}))

app.use('/session', routes.session);
app.use('/user', routes.user);
app.use('/schedule', routes.schedule);
app.use('/message', routes.message);
```

**2. API Method**

```js
//example values for simplicity
let correctEmail = "bob@gmail.com"
let correctPassword = "password"
let userId = 31 

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body
    if (email === correctEmail && password === correctPassword) { 
        req.session.user = userId
        req.session.save()
        console.log(req.session.user)     //31
        return res.sendStatus(200)
    } else {
        return res.status(400).send({error: "Those account details don't match our records"})
    } 
});

router.post('/checkAuth', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session.user)     //undefined
  if (req.session.user) {
    return res.sendStatus(200)
  } else {
    return res.status(400).send({error: "Not authenticated"})
  }
});
```

**3. Client side call**

```js
const login = async () => {
        const requestHeaders = {
            Accept: 'application/json',  
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST',
        }
        fetch(serverAddress + "/session/onboard/provider", { 
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: requestHeaders, 
            body: JSON.stringify(person)
        });
    }
    
const checkAuth = async () => {
        const requestHeaders = {
            Accept: 'application/json',  
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST',
        }
        fetch(serverAddress + "/session/checkAuth", { 
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: requestHeaders, 
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });
    }
```